# Determine Worflow Manager CU based on Build-Numbers

Tags: workflow-manager

By looking at these build numbers, how do I determine which CU I have on my Workflow Manager? I've looked online but can't find a list to help me figure this out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Workflow Manager, you can examine the build number of `C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts\Microsoft.Workflow.Service.dll`.

For Service Bus, look at `C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.1\Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.dll`.

[WFM CU5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055730/description-of-the-cumulative-update-5-for-workflow-manager-1-0) is the latest patch for Workflow Manager.

[Service Bus 1.1 with TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4077554/add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-on-service-bus-for-windows-server) is the latest patch for Service Bus 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "CU 2 - Workflow Manager 1.0" is what you are looking for

[image]

Please find [Here](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) the complete list of Workflow Manager 2013 Build Numbers

You will also find :

- SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers
- Office Web App 2013 Build Numbers
- App Fabric (Distributed Cache) Build Numbers